# Spring MVC JPA Native Insert With Generated Column Returned

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

These are the things I need to accomplish when inserting into PostgreSQL via JPA.

1) Insert to a table with the following added to the end of the insert "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" (Or some annotation if that exists)

2) Have the generated id column returned

Currently I am using the following method but it does not return the generated column...

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO table_name (value1) values(?1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING")
    int insertWithoutConflict(Long value1);
```

The solution I have that works without JPA involved is the following....

```
try(Connection conn = DatabaseUtils.getConnection()) {
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    statement.execute(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (resultSet.next())
        return resultSet.getLong(1);
}
```

Only problem with this is that I then am circumventing our current process and then have to start implementing a connection pool and I do not want to get into that. I want to know if this solution is possible in JPA or Hibernate.

Answer according to @Kayaman

```
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO My_Table(value_1, value_2) values(?1, ?2) RETURNING any_column")
    Long insertWithoutConflict(String value1, Long value2);
```

Can also return the model object I believe

```
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO My_Table(value_1, value_2) values(?1, ?2) RETURNING column_1, columnName_2, columnName_3, columnName_4")
    YourModelObject insertWithoutConflict(String value1, Long value2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `@Modifying` annotation, since it the query may not modify the data.

Then add `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING value1` (or `RETURNING *`), but you'll have to change that `int` to `Integer` since a conflict won't return any generated values.

Comment: Great answer, made me get to the final answer I needed. Can you modify your answer and state that for one I need to remove Modifying, And then I can return the Integer value that you stated? The Modifying made it so that I did not get results back. I removed that and was able to get Long or Integer or even the Model that I was using. I just have to return all the values in that model in the "RETURNING " parameter that was passed.

Comment: Once the answer is updated I will accept it! And hopefully it will help others out :)

Comment: Days of trying to figure out how to do this! AMAZING! This just opened my mind to how this stuff works. Great answer! Thanks for the help :)